# external SCSI tape drive DAT 72 problem Solaris 10

Tags: unix, solaris

I have solaris 10 sparc running and working very well
but i have problem with external SCSI tape drive DAT 72 problem 
it seems to me the tape drive is manufactured by SUN microsystems
when i ran **mt -f /dev/rmt/0 status**
it reveals the following output

```
bash-3.00#  mt -f /dev/rmt/0 status
/dev/rmt/0: No such file or directory
```

when i ran **ls -l** 
it reveals the following output

```
ls -l /dev/rmt/0
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root          43 Sep 20  2006 /dev/rmt/0 -> ../../devices/pci@8,600000/scsi@1,1/st@3,0:
```

it seems to me everything is okay 
SCSI cable is connected properly to Tape device and to server as well 
the tape has SCSI termination dongle as well and connected properly to Tape device as well
any ideas would be a great assist 
Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you get with "mt -t /dev/rmt/0n status" ?

Comment: Please make sure that's just a typo in your post
mt -t /dev/rmt/0n status
does mt has  a -t switch on solaris 
if not please confirm
anyways i ran it still getting same msg
bash-3.00# mt -t /dev/rmt/0n status
/dev/rmt/0n: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

When you look at the symlink destination "/devices/pci@8,600000/scsi@1,1/st@3,0:" does *that* exist.

Answer (score 1):

sorry for inconvenience
the instance number for external tape is 1 not 0

it works now very fine

```
bash-3.00# mt -f /dev/rmt/1 status
HP DAT-72 tape drive:
   sense key(0x6)= Unit Attention   residual= 0   retries= 0
   file no= 0   block no= 0
bash-3.00#
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# cfgadm -al 
Ap_Id                          Type         Receptacle   Occupant     Condition
...
c3                             scsi-bus     connected    configured   unknown
c3::rmt/8                      tape         connected    configured   unknown
```

last entry means that a tape drive is available, the device is : /dev/rmt/8